# Distributions with a specific property

Tags: normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm looking for examples of distributions for which $\frac{1  - F(t + \Delta t)}{1  - F(t)}  \to 0$  as  $t \to + \infty$, $\forall \Delta t >0$. Here $F$ is the cdf.

It looks like exponential doesn't work (memoryless). Gumbel distribution doesn't work either. Are there famous distributions for which this would work?

Comment: Normal distribution has this property.p (Apply L'Hopital's Rule). There are plenty of others.